# Android 10 Notification Images in Dark Mode looks like a negative image

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-10.0, android-darkmode

Android 10 Notification in Dark Mode looks like a negative image

Note: am not target my app to android 10 (API 29)

```
 minSdkVersion 17
 targetSdkVersion 28
```

Android 10 notification is shown below

[image]

In API 28 Dark Mode working fine

Comment: I hope it'll help you: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#configuration_changes

Comment: any solution ???

Comment: I mean how you solve this issue  Sarath Kumar

Answer (score 1):

Target version is outdated. Updated the targetSdkVersion to 29

Answer (score -1):

Give white background hardcoded in xml ,its working for me. 
however if screen locks and notification collapse then this problem persist.